# How to migrate an existing instance from Amazon EC2 to Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2

I have an application in centos VM running in amazon EC2 and now I need to migrate it to windows azure.
Is there a way to copy a snapshot to azure??

Comment: It is probably best to build up new images. Your EC2 instance has the centos support bits for EC2, while an Azure CentOS image (such as the OpenLogic one) will have the `waagent` installed and configured... ideally your setup scripts will be repeatable and documented to enable this.

Answer (score 0):

I wish to answer it step by step, but I found a link that is more than good & have almost details required to migrate an existing instance from Amazon EC2 to Windows Azure with video. The link is [Guided Hands-on Lab: Migrate VMs to Windows Azure from Amazon AWS [ 20 Key Cloud Scenarios with Windows Azure Infrastructure Services ]](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/05/31/guided-hands-on-lab-migrate-vms-to-windows-azure-from-amazon-aws-20-key-cloud-scenarios-with-windows-azure-infrastructure-services.aspx#.UsEVqfQW0y4)

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is only possible if you are running Windows Server on your EC2 instance by following this link:

https://convective.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/migrating-a-vm-from-ec2-to-azure-at-300-mbps/

If you're running linux, currently there's no simple tool that does it, but you can go to your Azure account and follow these steps:
1- Mimic your architecture of servers on your Azure account by keeping eyes on number of VMs, Network, Storages, and other services if found.
2- Make the correct setup on those servers (configure your web server, db server, etc..)
3- Zip all of your data files found on EC2 (/var/www/Web_Folder) and use mysqldump to backup your database as well.
4- Create a windows server VM on Azure that you can connect to Remotely (Profit from the cloud internet speed) and use filezilla to download your zipped files from EC2 and then upload them back to newly created VMs on Azure. Upload your db backup file there as well.
5- Create a new database on your Azure VMs with the same old name, give user access, exit mysql and then restore your db backup file that you uploaded using: mysql -u root -p DB_Name

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, Now you can accomplish this task using Azure Site Recovery this is a super easy task. In site recovery once you do failover all the virtual machines will automatically gets created which means with minimal or no downtime the migration can be performed https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/site-recovery-migrate-aws-to-azure/