# Download image of an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an amazon EC2 instance running. How can I have an image of the VM downloaded locally so that I can import it into some other cloud platform. I am using RHEL 7.3 free tier image for the VM. Will the image contain all the data I had on my VM?

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/questions/909405/download-ebs-volume-or-snapshot-to-file

Answer (score 1):

There is no in-built functionality to "download" an image of the VM.

You could create an ISO file of the disk (using standard utilities) and then download the ISO.

Also, see the [AWS VM Import/Export](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/) service. This allows you to export previously imported images (but not pure EC2 images).

**What is an 'instance'?**

This always raises the interesting question of what is an 'instance'? It is certainly a copy of the boot disk, which gives the virtual machine its 'personality'. However, it is also network placement, instance type, security group, tags, etc. These other factors typically aren't needed to move an instance out of AWS, because they are AWS-specific.

Comment: Yes I noticed that we cannot export a pure EC2 instance. So there is no way we can have a EC2 instance migrate to some other cloud?

Comment: There seem to be some pages on the web, such as [How to migrate an existing instance from Amazon EC2 to Windows Azure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834558/how-to-migrate-an-existing-instance-from-amazon-ec2-to-windows-azure).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, For second part of your question. Images contains all the data of the EC2-instance (VM).

You should check this for copying ec2 Instance Image 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html

Comment: This talks about copying AMIs from one AWS region/account to another. What if I want to import into a new cloud environment altogether. For example softlayer.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/migrating-vm-ec2-azure-300, this show migration of vm-ec2 to Azure, maybe this can help you